# Action creator is called but action is not dispatched

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a component that successfully uses redux-form onSubmit to call an action creator. The creator performs an ajax call but the the action is never dispatched to save it to the store. I must have something messed up in the wiring of react-redux and redux-form, possibly in the binding of the action creator. I have read everything that I have found on Google and still can't find the problem. Any ideas? ( I have included redux-promise to handle the request promise, but it never makes it that far )

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import validate from '../utils/add_person_validation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addPersonResponseAction } from '../actions/index';
import renderField from '../components/render_input_field';

// call the action creator - this part succeeds 
const doSubmit = function(values) {
  addPersonResponseAction(values);
};


let AddPersonContainer = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting
  } = props;


  return (
    <div className="row">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(doSubmit)} >
          <div className="col-sm-6">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Person Info</legend>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <Field name="personFirstName" component={renderField} type="text" label="First Name" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="personLastName" component={renderField} type="text" label="Last Name" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="birthday" component={renderField} type="date" label="Birthday" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="group" component={renderField} type="text" label="Group" className="form-control" />
                </div>
              </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div className="form-buttons-container">
            <button className="btn btn-default form-button" type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
            <button className="btn btn-default form-button" type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div> 
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = function({ addPersonResponse }) {
  return { addPersonResponse };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators( {addPersonResponseAction}, dispatch);
};

const form = reduxForm({ form: 'addPerson', validate: validate });

AddPersonContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form(AddPersonContainer));

export default AddPersonContainer;

/********************************************
* Action creator
**********************************************/

import axios from 'axios';

export const ADD_PERSON_RESPONSE = 'ADD_PERSON_RESPONSE';

export const addPersonResponseAction = (data) => {

  const postURL = 'http://some-url/addperson';
  const request = axios.post(postURL, { data });

  return {
    type: ADD_PERSON_RESPONSE,
    payload: request
  };

};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Redux wraps actions using `mapDispatchToProps` - but you are calling the unwrapped version by using the imported method.

```
// call the action creator - this part succeeds 
const doSubmit = function(values) {
  addPersonResponseAction(values);    <------ Redux does not know anything about this
};
```

Try:

```
let AddPersonContainer = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting
  } = props;

  const doSubmit = function(values) {
    props.addPersonResponseAction(values);  <----- Try this
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(doSubmit)} >
          <div className="col-sm-6">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Person Info</legend>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <Field name="personFirstName" component={renderField} type="text" label="First Name" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="personLastName" component={renderField} type="text" label="Last Name" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="birthday" component={renderField} type="date" label="Birthday" className="form-control" />
                  <Field name="group" component={renderField} type="text" label="Group" className="form-control" />
                </div>
              </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div className="form-buttons-container">
            <button className="btn btn-default form-button" type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
            <button className="btn btn-default form-button" type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div> 
  );
};
```

Because the function you are defining does not have access to props this gives a bit of a twist, so try refactoring it into the component definition.

This is a source of confusion because it is required to import the function so `mapDispatchToProps` can wrap it...but there is temptation to forget that the real action is in `props`, not the function itself. So I'm sure you are seeing results in the actual action function, but redux does not know because it is not wrapped in `dispatch`.

Comment: Thank You! I knew I was just overlooking something! Works perfectly now.

Comment: To add to this, make sure you've combined your reducer into the root reducer.

Comment: Thank you. I was gonna punch a hole in my laptop.